# Exclude a database with pg_upgrade?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgresql 15 and would like to upgrade to 16.

One of my databases is [giving me some grief](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78227454/651980) and I'd actually like to exclude it from the upgrade process, by which I mean simply not bring into the new cluster. I think under the hood, pg_upgrade uses `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`. I know `pg_dumpall` has an `--exclude-database` option. Yes I'm aware that it would be simpler to drop said DB first, but I'm in a kubernetes initContainer and postgres isn't running yet at this point. That will be my plan B.

I wonder if there's a way using the `--old-options` switch (or anything else) to somehow skip over a database during `pg_upgrade`?

Comment: The only RDBMS able of having databases working in different versions of the engine is Microsoft SQL Server, and this in backward compatibility mode since version 2008... Unfortunately this does not exist in PostgreSQL. You will need to exclude this database from your upgrade and put it in a cluster of the same level as currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not possible, pg_upgrade migrates a complete cluster including everything to a newer version. It's a binary upgrade, not a SQL dump&restore like pg_dump/pg_dumpall and pg_restore. Check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html